# Storing certain array content in a variable

Tags: arrays, powershell

I have the following array:

```
$webApplications = Get-SPWebApplication | Select-Object Url
```

which gives output similar to this:

```
http://testportal.*******de
http://testportal2.******de
```

I would like the output to be numbered like this for example:

```
1- http://testportal.*******de
2- http://testportal2.******de
```

and then store them in variables and have the user be able to choose the portal they want by typing in only the number of the portal. I tried something like this to store them in variables (not sure if it's the right approach):

```
$Variable1 = $webApplications[0]
$Variable2 = $webApplications[1]
$SelectedURL = Read-Host 'choose your portal by selecting a number'
```

I just can't seem to figure out how to list the content of the array with numbers on the side and then call it back for the `$SelectedURL` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do what you're trying to do. Using dynamic variable names is an anti-pattern.

Do something like this instead:

```
for ($i=0; $i -lt $webApplications.Count; $i++) {
    '{0} - {1}' -f ($i+1), $webApplications[$i]
}
[int]$SelectedURL = Read-Host 'choose your portal by selecting a number'

$webApplications[($SelectedURL - 1)]
```

Comment: This gave me the result i was hoping for, thank you very much, if you could maybe explain to me this real quick i'd appreciate it :) **($i=0; $i -lt $webApplications.Count; $i++) {
    '{0} - {1}' -f ($i+1), $webApplications[$i**

Comment: The loop is a regular [`for` loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop) and in the body of that loop I'm using the [format operator](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7855.powershell-using-the-f-format-operator.aspx) for creating formatted output.